# React Axios ECONNRESET on POST request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, fetch

I am working using Node and React.js.

Sending something to the server using the GET method is working fine with fetch and axios, but when I use the POST method, I get the following error:

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /user/createUser from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3300.

See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNRESET).
```

The request is visible in the server log, but body and params are not sent.

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: Provide request code and request flow details (react web->proxy?->server). If its your API server then could be server or networking issues. Probably a common CORS problem due to GET request working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your kindness.

I solved this problems.
It caused by not using body-parser.
even now, however, I am curious whether I always need Body-parser when I send data from client to API.